# Is there a difference between botchan and musuko-san?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking at translations of "your son". I see two different ones.

I would appreciate if someone could help and tell me the difference.

Comment: Is romaji all you can read?

Comment: Maybe you want to register, so you don't create a new account each time you ask a question. (This seems to be your third post.)

Answer (score 1):

*Botchan* is almost an archaic word nowadays. It also has a connotation that "he was born with a silver spoon" especially when it's used as *O-botchan*.

Always use *musuko-san*, and you won't get into any troubles (except, obviously, for confusing a baby girl with a baby boy... *O-ko-san* is a polite and gender-neutral word for a "kid.")